# Variable Filenames and Curlib

Tags: c, variables, filenames, libcurl

What I want to do:

I am trying to write a c program that will download a file from a URL and save it locally, I found the following guide and it does exactly what I want as long as I hard code the file names:

http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-and-save-onto-local-directory-in-c-using-libcurl/

What is my problem:

The files get updated hourly, with each new file date and time stamped. I can predict the required filename using time.h and extracting the current date and time information, however I can't work out how to combine this information into a form I can pass to the curlib commands.

Current Attempted Solution (doesn't work):

```
char *url;                       //char pointer to URL
url = malloc((sizeof(char)*51+1);//allocate memory to pointer address is 51 characters + \0 terminator
sprintf(url, "http://>URL Info</FILENAME%.4d%.2d%.2d%.2d30.jpg\0", year, month, date, hour);
                                 //ie http://example.com/files/FILENAME201304071030.jpg
```

The string is being filled as I can output it with printf, however it doesn't seem to get passed to the curlib command:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```

It creates the destination file, but the file is empty. I suspect it has something to do with the difference between a char pointer and a string, but I'm not sure what.

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong and what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTVERBOSE) option in your libcurl-using program and inspect the request/response being sent.

My guess is that you somehow just asks for the wrong URL and the server responds with a 404 or something else with no actual response body content.

The [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); call you showed seems fine as in it takes a zero terminated char *, and that's what you sent to it. Of course, the VERBOSE output will also show you if libcurl does treat the input the same way you expect it to.

Comment: In the end I'd made the silliest of errors. My program was working in local time, but the images I wanted to download were based on UTC. Once I had that sorted it all works fine...